# Что такое обычный JOIN?

Tags: mysql

Что такое обычный join

это left join?

или inner join?

как вы считаете?

Comment: Голосую за inner.

Comment: мы считаем, что лучше узнать у гугля. а то всякое может быть. вдруг документацию переписали, а мужики не в курсе.

Comment: гугл не вкурсе

вопрос с собеседования

какие джойны вы знаете? - лефт джоин, раит джоин и обычный джоин - ответил я

обычный джоин это лефт джоин сказали мне

но я так не считаю

считаю обычным джойном иннер джоин так как он обычный

Comment: если бы вы сказали лефт, раит и иннер вас бы не поправляли. бтв, есть еще кросс, который такой же как иннер и как просто джойн, еще есть стрейт и нэйчерал. данный вопрос на собеседовании - приглашение к диалогу, а не вопрос на засыпку. Если вы в теме, то таким вопросом сбить с толку нельзя. И после драки кулаками не машут. да.

Answer (score 5):

Из [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html):

```
 In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.
```

Comment: В MySQL `JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` и `INNER JOIN` — одно и то же. В стандартном SQL, они *НЕ* эквивалентны: `INNER JOIN` используется с уточнением `ON`, а в прочих случаях используется `CROSS JOIN`.
(мой перевод)

Answer (score 1):

Outer Join  может быть как **left** и right сам **"outer"** опускается. Само по себе **join** использовать не будем, лишь в совокупности с **"left inner right outer cross"**. Так что обычный **"JOIN"** будем считать просто оператором.

Answer (score 0):

"вопрос с собеседования какие джойны вы знаете? - лефт джоин, раит джоин и обычный джоин - ответил я".

Сколько людей столько мнений. Представьте себя разработчиком у которого есть
ТЗ а в нем написано: "эти таблицы соединяем обычным джином". Я бы такое ТЗ не принял - отправил бы на уточнение.

Comment: посмотри когда был задан вопрос - более двух лет назад!

Answer (score 0):

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INNER | JOIN | Возвращает записи которые имеют соответствие в обеих таблицах |
| OUTER | LEFT JOIN | Возвращает все записи из левой таблицы + записи которые имеют соответствие из правой |
| OUTER | RIGHT JOIN | Возвращает все записи из правой таблицы + записи которые имеют соответствие из левой |
| OUTER | FULL JOIN | Возвращает все записи из обеих таблиц |